# Data Cardinality

Tags: database, relational-database, relationship, cardinality

I'm confusing about 0:M relationship.

So, I want to ask about that.

Assumes we have 2 tables :

Contact which has attributes like : ContactID(PK),
                                    Name

Address which has attributes like : AddressID(PK), 
                                    Desc, 
                                    ContactID(FK to Contact, Nullable, Not Unique)

Is my statement right that :

- The 0:M relationship occurred when there is 1 row in Contact and it's ContactID don't appear in Address.
- To make the 0:M relationship Column ContactID in Table Address must be nullable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `0:M` notation is used to annotate one side of a relationship, indicating its cardinality. It is a range and is accurate in every instance of the relationship. When ContactID doesn't occur in address, the cardinality is 0.
- Foreign keys don't need to be nullable, and shouldn't in general. The 0 case still happens, when a ContactID occurs in Contact and not Address.